# Documentum API in java

Tags: java, api, documentum

I am currently using DQMAN for my OpenText Documentum. I use it for DQL and API. Now that i am using a java program to run my dql (with the help of DFC), i also need a way to run my API commands in java.
Eg : of my API command : getpath,c,090xxxxxxxx27

How does that need to be done in java  ?

Answer (score 0):

`IDfSession` interface has these methods:

- `apiDesc(command)` - which returns description of the command, where from value on index 2 you can resolve what type of the command it is if you need to execute commands dynamically (passed from user for example). Possible values are:

  - *0* - get
  - *1* - set
  - *2* - exec
- `apiGet(method, arguments)` - for get commands like `get`, `getpath`, `getcontent`, ...
- `apiSet(method, arguments, value)` - for set commands like `set`, `append`, ...
- `apiExec(method, arguments)` - for exec commands like `abort`, `lock`, ...

For example in your case of `getpath,c,090xxxxxxxx27` API command you will do it by DFC this way:

```
session.apiGet("getpath", "090xxxxxxxx27");
```

I hope that these `IDfSession` methods are still available, because they were deprecated. At least in 16.4 (the last Documentum version I worked with) they still were there.

But lot of commands have their corresponding counterpart as direct DFC methods. For example object content storage path can be also retrieved by:

```
IDfSysObject object = session.getObject(new DfId("090xxxxxxxx27"))
String path = object.getPath(0)
```

Or if you need path for specific rendition format then you can use `getPathEx2()` method with `formatName` argument.

Comment: Hey !! Thanks but as u guessed the  "session.apiGet" is deprecated :/ And session.getObjectPaths(new DfId("090xxxxxxxx27")) doesnt give e the same output as the apiGet. Any other possible way ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I'm slowly forgetting how it worked in Documentum :-) The right counterpart for `getpath` api command is `IDfSysObject.getPath()` method or alternatively `getPathEx()` and `getPathEx2()`.